# How do I transfer Vue.js and socket.io code from my HTML file to seperate components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, socket.io

I'm new to vue.js and socket.io, I followed a tutorial on YouTube and I want to continue working on what I've done in the tutorial, but the author kept everything in two files. So I have index.html that looks something like this:

```
<body>

(HTML here)

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
        var socket = io();
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
            ...
            ...
        created() {
            ...
            (socket.io code)
            ...
         }})
</script>
</body>
```

And my index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

(socket.io code)
```

I really want to somehow make this project easier to manage by not doing everything in the index.html file, rather create multiple .vue files, I still didn't quite get how I could do this, any help please?

Comment: Create [components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: Where do I create them and how would I transfer data between index.html and components? Would I need templates for that?

Comment: I assume you are using cli to create js from the `.vue` files correct?

Comment: I currently don't have any `.vue` files, but I want to use cli to create components from the script part of my `index.html` file, which is run by CDN

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html and then https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html.  Essentially just `npm install -g @vue/cli` on the command line, and then `vue create myproject`.  [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is ideal too if you're not already using it, the terminal is integrated nicely with their directory viewer / file editor.

Comment: Here is another tutorial https://travishorn.com/getting-started-with-vue-single-file-components-f29765a771a3